# API returns empty body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

So I have the following two API methods:

```
//GET person
public IEnumerable<Person> Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> persons = context.Person.AsEnumerable();
    foreach(Person p in persons){
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.FirstName); //prints out all names
    }
    return persons; //returns empty body
}
//GET person/{id}
public Person Index(int id)
{
    return context.Person.Find(id);

}
```

This is my request:

```
GET /person HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:55073
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

And the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcamVzcGVyXGRvY3VtZW50c1x2aXN1YWwgc3R1ZGlvIDIwMTJcUHJvamVjdHNcV29ya1Rlc3RcV29ya1Rlc3RcZW1wbG95ZWU=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:33:37 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Why are the Content-length 0?

Also, why do I get a 404 resource not found when I try to call the second API method?

This is my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I'm using Asp.net MVC 4 Web API with Unity WebAPI if that makes any difference.

Edit:
It seems like I have misconfigured Unity somehow. I fixed an error in my `PersonController` and then got this error:

> Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

In my `global.asax` file I this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstrapper.Initialise();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

and the Bootstrapper.cs looks like this

```
public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
{
    var container = BuildUnityContainer();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    return container;
}

private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IRepository<Person, int>, PersonRepository>();   
    RegisterTypes(container);

    return container;
}
```

From what I have read this is all you need to change to get it working?

Comment: It is 0 either because there are no records or the result is not being enumerated by the model binder. Try changing return type to a list and use `ToList` extension and see if you get a result. For your second question you have not shown the request that is getting `404` also show your route configuration for the api it could provide a clue.

Comment: There are records(I can see them when printing in the for loop).
I tried changing the return to List but result was the same. I then tried to change return type to string and return "AString" but that got the same results aswell.

Comment: based on your default route config the second action would map to something like `person/index/5` and not `person/5` like in your comment above the method in your example

Comment: Also the route config you are showing is for MVC not Web API. look for `WebApiConfig` class and you should see your `HttpConfiguration` there. Does your `PersonController` inherit from `ApiController` or just `Controller`

Comment: I actually found an error in the PersonController which might have caused this, but then i got another error instead. I've updated my question with more information.

Comment: Again. Is your controller a MVC Controller or an ApiController. The dependency resolver you are configuring is for MVC not WebApi. they have different setups.

Comment: It was an ApiController, once I changed it to Controller it started working like intended! :) Thank you alot!